# Distance of two Rectangle Center's Connecting Line Outside of the Rectangles

Tags: geometry, algorithms

Well excuse me for the long title, i dont really know how to call it.

[image]

I would like you to explain me how to calculate the image's red line's length, knowing the rectangles position and dimensions.

Context: I need this for a 2d game collision response since when the length is negative it means not only they are intersecting but also that length is the distance they have to repel each other to stop being collided. If there's an easier way to do this, even better.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Pythagoras' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagoras_theorem)?

Comment: ye i am, how would you use it to solve this?

Comment: Start by drawing a right triangle whose hypotenuse is that diagonal line you've got in your picture.

Comment: Ye, im not following you, i dont want the distance of the line between the centers, my red line isnt the whole line, its just the outside of the square yes, otherwise i wouldnt be asking for help

Comment: @Oli The question is asking about the length of the *red* line in the image, not just the distance between the centres.

Comment: @Tharwen: Yes, I realise that ;)

Comment: take a look of this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115426/algorithm-to-detect-intersection-of-two-rectangles?rq=1

Comment: OK, you still start by drawing a right triangle whose hypotenuse is the entire diagonal line.  Then you notice that the big triangle contains two smaller triangles, which are similar to the big one, so that the sides will be proportional.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about geometry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
We have two rectangles one centred at A the the other on B.

If the position of A is $(x_a,y_a)$ and the position of B is $(x_b,y_b)$ We can use Pythagoras to determine the length AB.

$$ AB = \sqrt{(x_b-x_a)^2 + (y_b-y_a)^2}$$

Now we are only interested in the distance DE.  We know AC as its half the width of the rectangle centred on A call it $\frac{W_a}{2}$ and we know EF as its half the width of the rectangle centred on B call it $\frac{W_b}{2}$. We also AG its $x_b-x_a$

We can use ratios because for example $\frac{AD}{AB} = \frac{AC}{AG}$

The distance DE is thus:

$$
DE = \sqrt{(x_b-x_a)^2 + (y_b-y_a)^2} \cdot \frac{x_b-x_a - \frac{W_a}{2} - \frac{W_b}{2}}{x_b-x_a}
$$

Given that A and B could be anywhere then you may also need to consider what happens when B is much higher than A so the line between them does not go through the sides of both rectangles but goes out of the top or bottom of one or both of the rectangles instead.  But all these combinations can be solved in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks I got it, i might use the angle between the rectangles to make it more universal though

Comment: What if rectangles are rotated, say the length of one of them makes some angle with the length of other one (and they are non-overlapping) ?

Answer (score 0):

Lets Assume X1, Y1, H1, W1 for rec 1's dimensions.
Same for Rec 2.

For the x dimension, if distance between X1 and X2 is less than half of W1 and W2, then they *could* be collision.

Same check can be done for Y. If both X and Y dimensions have dimensional-collision, then there is object collision.

So:
If ( abs(X1-X2) < (W1+W2)/2 && abs(Y1-Y2) < (H1+H2)/2 ) then Collision !

I haven't double checked it for all edge cases...

Comment: That is detection, not response, my goal of the whole question is to have data to respond to the collision, detecting it isnt the problem

Comment: You could use similar equation to determine area of intersection, which could be used as to calculate a repulsion force, if that is your goal.

The formula would look like: 
( (W1+W2)/2 - abs(X1-X2) ) * ( (H1+H2)/2 - abs(Y1-Y2) )

This could be higher performance algorithm if you are looking for an approximation.